# ESRI Raster Calculator error "Con()"

Tags: raster-calculator, arcgis-10.6

I"m trying to nest expressions in this raster calculator conditional statement, but I get an error.

This statement works, so I tried to follow it as a template:

```
Con (IsNull("ras1"),"ras2","ras3")
```

Separately, this statement works

```
"rasB"-(5+(1/(1+"rasC"))*5)*("RasD"<=20)
```

And I'd love to merge them into one calulation liek this

```
Con(IsNull("rasA"),
("rasB"-(5+(1/(1+"rasC"))*5)*("RasD"<=20),
("rasB"-(5+(1/(1+"rasC"))*5)*("RasD"<=500))))
```

Where "rasA" is null, return "rasB"-(5+(1/(1+"rasC"))*5)*("RasD"<=20). Otherwise return "rasB"-(5+(1/(1+"rasC"))*5)*("RasD"<=500)

I get the error shown below so I'm trying to figure out if **Con() requires a *layer* like the error says or if can I use an expression and I just entered it wrong.**

[image]

Comment: Please remember to place the complete error text in the question as ASCII. This makes it legible on all platforms and available for search by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parentheses are incorrect. You have parentheses around both the True and False expressions, i.e:

```
Con(condition, (true_expression, false_expression))
```

It should be:

```
Con(condition, true_expression, false_expression)
```

Try:

```
Con(IsNull("rasA"), "rasB"-(5+(1/(1+"rasC"))*5)*("RasD"<=20), "rasB"-(5+(1/(1+"rasC"))*5)*("RasD"<=500))
```

Or:

```
Con(IsNull("rasA"), ("rasB"-(5+(1/(1+"rasC"))*5)*("RasD"<=20)), ("rasB"-(5+(1/(1+"rasC"))*5)*("RasD"<=500)))
```

Comment: Parentheses...I always miss some mundane detail like that!  point of clarification...  in your answer, instead of Con(condition, true_expression, true_expression)  should it be Con(condition, true_expression, FALSE_expression) ?